# How to pass an object to an MVC Contoller Method using $.ajax?

Tags: jquery, .net, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've been fiddling with the default MVC fiddle on [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GnsYki). The default picks a random answer to any question (or an non-null text entered). I am trying to get it to give a specific answer ("No one!") to any question that contains the word "Who".

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetAnswer(SampleViewModel qa)
{   
    Console.Write(qa);
    int index = _rnd.Next(_db.Count);
    if (qa.Question != null)
    {
         qa.Answer = qa.Question.Contains("Who") ? "No one!" : _db[index];
    }
    Console.WriteLine(qa);
    return Json(qa);
}
```

The default GetAnswer method, which is called on POST, had a string parameter named question. I don't know why that should be, as the ajax call passes/ed an object with two string members (Answer and Question) to the method. I've changed it to accept an object SampleViewModel type, which has two string members.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.RouteUrl( new { action="GetAnswer", controller="Home"})',
        data: {Answer: "", Question: $('#Question').val()},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(resp) {
                    console.log(resp);
                    openAlert(resp.Answer);
}});
```

I haven't changed that object passed. I *have*, though, changed the JSON object sent back from method (to a SampleViewModel obj) and then, in the ajax success function, am sending just the Answer in the object to a js function that updates the text in a span. (I haven't changed any of the said js/jquery code other than in the ajax call).

The problem is that the controller method always seems to be getting a null object passed in. Console.Write() for some reason isn't working in this fiddle, but I've tried this project in VS Code with debugger and confirmed that.

How do I get the object correctly passed in to the method?

Edit: When I examine $('#Question').val() in the Chrome developer console, it does indeed always show the text entered in the question text-box.

Edit(2): The SampleViewModel definition:

```
namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
{
    public class SampleViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [MinLength(10)]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        [Display(Name = "Ask Magic 8 Ball any question:")]
        public string Question { get; set; }

        //See here for list of answers
        public string Answer { get; set; }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of `SampleViewModel` class?

Comment: @shankar It's viewable in the fiddle, but okay, I'll include it in the question in a bit..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `contentType` from your ajax call. If you make it `application/json`, you'd have to stringify.

[Updated fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BfIEH8)

Comment: Click on the checkmark on the left side of the answer. ([Accepting Answers: How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289255))